# How to use Maven to download from Nexus for a deployment

Tags: maven, nexus, bamboo

I am somewhat new to Maven but we are successfully using Bamboo to deploy to Tomcat using Maven and Tomcat7 plugin.  However I want a separate Bamboo build plan that only deploys a war package from Nexus, does not re-build it first.  Looks like I could make the war a dependency but this same POM builds the package, so I don't want it downloaded in the case that a build goal is called.

Comment: I forgot to mention, Bamboo impacts this since for each new plan it creates a build directory.  Therefore for a new 'deployment' plan, the build is not readily available.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/). It should be easy to have a project grab an existing war artifact and push it to tomcat.

Comment: Maven is primarily a build tool. Must take care not to overuse it for items like deployment. For example, unless you're using a plugin like "cargo" your solution would require Maven to be run on the target machine. I would submit it's simpler to SSH into the target machine and simply download the required version directly from the Maven repository using commands like wget or curl.

Comment: Agreed. But it also bring benefits to other CM related activities in term of uniformity of packaging, invocation conventions, etc. Wether deployment is part of the build or not really depends what you're doing with it (i.e. deployment to a test system in order to run CI integration testing could arguably be part of the build workflow).

Comment: If you also do your production deployments using Maven, then I can agree. In practice this rarely happens. I'd recommend reading the following blog which discusses the need to standardize the deployment pipeline across all environments: http://zkybase.org/blog/2012/11/10/a-fatal-impedance-mismatch-for-continuous-delivery/

Answer (score 1):

Nexus has a very rich REST API that you could easily use to script the deployment with a simple http get and a copy. However if you really feel like you want to use Maven ptyx approach should work ... although it seems like overkill. If you invest into effort for deployment I would look into using Chef or Puppet instead and use them to pull from Nexus and push into your production (or QA or whatever servers).

Comment: See following Sonatype link for example Bash script using Nexus REST API: http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/01/downloading-artifacts-from-nexus-with-bash/